# finding solution of differential equation $y''-9y=(x^2-2)\sin(4x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Using method of undetermined coefficient finding solution of $y''-9y=(x^2-2)\sin(4x)$

What i try: First we will find characteristic solution

$r^2-9=0\Longrightarrow r=\pm 3$

So our characteristic solution

$y_{c}(x)=C_{1}e^{3x}+C_{2}e^{-3x}$

But i did not understand How can i find perticular solution.

How do i solve it help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But i did not understand How can i find perticular solution.

The exercise explicitly asks you to use the **method of undetermined coefficients**: perhaps you could explain what you don't understand about this method? There are plenty of examples (on this site, other websites, youtube) available to see how the method works.

Note that you could save yourself a bit of time and work though.

> Using method of undetermined coefficient finding solution of $y''-9y=\color{blue}{(x^2-2)\sin(4x)}$

Based on the right-hand side, you would generally [suggest a particular solution $y_p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients#Typical_forms_of_the_particular_integral) of the form:
$$y_p = \left(Ax^2+Bx+C\right)\sin(4x)+\left(Dx^2+Ex+F\right)\cos(4x) \tag{$*$}$$
and this leads to a system of 6 equations in the 6 unknowns ("undetermined coefficients") $A,\ldots,F$.

However, $\color{blue}{(x^2-2)\sin(4x)}$ is an odd function so $y''-9y$ has to be odd which implies that $y$ has to be odd. Therefore only the coefficients in $(*)$ corresponding to odd functions will be non-zero and you immediately have $B=D=F=0$ as those correspond to even functions. The system is reduced to a 3-by-3.

Comment: Very useful observation to reduce work in half +1.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** There are several approaches for finding particular solution for non-homogeneous linear differential equation of second order with constant coefficients. I will recommend this [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients) (method of undetermined coefficients).